# Jqgrid Masking phone number should save in the same format and position

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jquery.jqgrid version  v4.4.4, mvc 5.
In my inline jqgrid, i have Phone Number colModel need to be mask in US Phone number format and my code looks like,

```
{
        name: 'PhoneNumber', index: 'PhoneNumber', editable: true, sortable: true, width: 300, classes: "grid-col",           
        editoptions: { dataInit: function (elem) {
                $(elem).mask("?(999) 999-9999");
                $(this).val(elem);                  
            }
        }
},
```

If i type like this'(454)453-3233' the field(textbox) holds the correct value and get saved as '4544533233' in database correctly. To remove the brackets and hypen i used,

```
 PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber.replace(/\D/g, ''); //Removes anything that is not a digit \D
```

The issue is, 
First,if i type like this '( 54)4  -  65' then the field formatted itself and holds (544)65 which is wrong.

Second, the existing phone numbers are not masked, displays in the grid without mask format.

1).How to make the field to hold and save the input with same position as i typed?

2).How to display the existing Phone Number('4544533233'stored like this in db) in mask format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
colModel[{ name: 'DOB', width: 75, editable: true, formatter: dateFormatter, editoptions: { class: 'isDateField' } }]


//dateFormatter function to format before saving
 function dateFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
            if (cellvalue !== undefined) {
                var formattedValue = (cellvalue.slice(0, 4) + '/' + cellvalue.slice(4, 6) + '/' + cellvalue.slice(6, 8));
                if (formattedValue==='//') {
                    return ('');
                }
                return formattedValue;
            }
        };
```

Comment: you can use the formatter property to format the input before saving the above example is to format date '20141225' to '2014/12/25'